# Implementing nestjsx/crud

Tags: nestjs

I'm learning nestjs recently and while integrating nestjsx/crud I'm getting an error. Please help me resolve it.[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZobR.png)

I tried to implement basic CRUD operations on the data stored in my postgresql database.None of the end points are working.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into the official CRUD doc.

[crud-generator](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/crud-generator)

use `nest g resource` to easily implement